# tableau row level calculations

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculated field where it calculates the no. of days the case is with CSE i.e., support engineers, for that I have created 2 calculated fields cse-anything(cse-A date) and anything - CSE (A-CSE Date).

I need to take the diff between these two date fields, but the problem is for a particular case it a case can move `n` no. of times to CSE. I need to find the diff between all the days and sum them up.

But the dates are in different level like:

```
case id  a-cse  cse-a
101       null   10/19/18
          null . 11/19/18
         9/19/18  null
         10/19/18 null
```

In A-CSE I have to replace the null values with 9/19/18 and 10/19/18 and find diff.

[image]

Comment: are you facing problem with null values?

Comment: Yes, bcoz the values are null in A-CSE Date I cant use a datediff function.I want to replace the null values with the below values .

Comment: Can you add sample data few rows so that it will be helpful to provide solution

Comment: I have attached the image of view .

Comment: are you getting a NULL value or null string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have string `null` in the `a-cse` and `a-cse` is of string datatype.

Create a formula and write below code:

```
IF a-cse="null"
THEN
(REPLACE(a-cse,"null","9/19/18" ))
ELSE
a-cse
END
```

Create one more formula and write below code:

```
DATE(([Calculation1]))
```

Do same for both the columsn now both columns have date datatype you can get the difference

Comment: My fields are of Date type only

Comment: How can be null string stored in date type field?

Comment: (IF ([Old Value]!='CSE - Work in Progress' AND  
[New Value]= 'CSE - Work in Progress' )
THEN ([History  Created Date])
END . This was the calculated field I have created for calculating the date ,so if fails the condition it throws out to be null

Comment: My question here is in image there is `null` for few rows and few rows have date, my question are you getting string `null` in tableau? because null is not a date datatype both are different. History Created Date may be field name but it need not necessary to be a date datatype